# Sequelize Migrations in folders

Tags: reactjs, sequelize.js, database-migration, next.js13

We wanted to keep our migrations in their own folders

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
   'seeders-path': path.resolve('src/database', 'seeders'),
   'migrations-path': path.resolve('src/database/migrations'),
   'migrations-path': path.resolve('src/database/migrations/20230920-model'),
   'migrations-path': path.resolve('src/database/migrations/20231002-other_model'),
   'migrations-path': path.resolve('src/database/migrations/20231004-third_model'),
   'config': path.resolve('src/database', 'config.ts'),
}
```

the 1002 and 1004 were part of different commits, when we merged to master and ran
`npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`
only the 1004 migration was applied.

how do we make sure that all unapplied migrations get applied?